# AbsoluteLayout with proportional height and with minimum and maximum heights

Tags: xaml, xamarin

We need a banner, called bannerView in the code bellow, to shrink or expand according to the device height.

However this banner height:

- cannot be smaller than 60 units
- cannot be bigger than 146 units

code:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <StackLayout
        Padding="0"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <AbsoluteLayout
            x:Name="bannerView">
            <Image
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1.05,1"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional"
                Aspect="AspectFill"
                Source="banner.jpg">
            </Image>
            <Label
                Margin="16,18,16,36"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,-1,-1"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                Text="{Binding Name}">
            </Label>
            <Label
                Margin="16,18,16,18"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,-1,-1"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                Text="{Binding EmployeeId}">
            </Label>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <!-- Dynamic content -->
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Note: We need the outer AbsoluteLayout to add a gradient effect on the screen

Comment: Pixels isn't such a good way i would say every device has a different perception of pixels

Comment: You are right. I meant units not pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the possibility to use a FlexLayout containing the banner view element, and this one having the HeightRequest attribute binded to view model?

I used something similar as ControlTemplate to achieve a custom page's header depending on the device navigation bar height:

```
<FlexLayout Direction="Column" JustifyContent="Center">
    <!--HEADER-->
    <Grid IsVisible="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.ToolbarVisibled}" HeightRequest="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.ToolbarHeight}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".8*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--...-->
    </Grid>
    <!--CONTENT HERE-->
    <FlexLayout Direction="Column" JustifyContent="Center">
        <ContentPresenter FlexLayout.Grow="1"/>
    </FlexLayout>
</FlexLayout>
```